# Acronis True Image EE Server taking over network PXE booting?

Tags: boot, pxe-boot, acronis

I have about 5 servers that I run Acronis True Image EE server on for image backups on a company network.

For a few weeks now, I've received reports of company desktop end users booting up their PC's and getting the Acronis recovery boot up screen. Assuming this is true, I want to verify that my own Acronis installs are not somehow taking over the PXE booting of random company machines that are set to boot from PXE before hard drive.

As far as I know, the only Acronis components I have installed on the servers is True Image Echo Enterprise Server. To my knowledge I don't have Acronis Snap Deploy PXE server installed or any other agent software.

My question is: How would I go about tracing where a PXE boot might be booting from? (e.g. find the PXE server's ip address or machine name).

Or has anyone ever heard of Acronis True Image EE Server taking over PXE booting?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect as a starting point I would just startup wireshark on a network where you are having this issue, and then release and renew the dhcp address of the wireshark computer.  Watch all the dhcp traffic, and you should see the offers from that include the pxe server you are having problems with.  See the question "[How do I find if there is a rogue DHCP server on my Network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8526/how-do-i-find-if-there-is-a-rogue-dhcp-server-on-my-network)" for some more insight.