# Temporary failure in Name Resolution to internal host

Tags: internal-dns, ubuntu-18.04

I have recently installed 2 virtual machines using Ubuntu 18.04, both appear to be configured the same, but one will not resolve addresses.

Both servers have a minimal install.

Server 1 runs nginx proxy server.
Server 2 runs bind for external DNS

Both servers point to 10.0.181.1 and 10.0.181.2 in their netplan config for DNS.

Both servers have no firewall enabled locally.

Both servers can ping the internal DNS servers.

Server 2:

```
root@uksvl-ops01:/etc/netplan# ping uksvl-web01-rs
PING uksvl-web01-rs (10.0.52.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from uksvl-web01-rs (10.0.52.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.19 ms
```

Server 1:

```
root@uksvl-web01-ki:/etc/nginx/conf.d# ping uksvl-web01-rs
ping: uksvl-web01-rs: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I have seen references to disabling systemd-resolve, this has no impact.

There is no DHCP involved here, everything is static.

Comment: Check the actual content of `/etc/resolv.conf` and make sure it is sensible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temporary failure in name resolution](https://serverfault.com/questions/266042/temporary-failure-in-name-resolution)

Comment: @MichaelHampton resolv.conf is identical on both.

Comment: Huh. I just noticed that you aren't using FQDNs. You should get in the habit of doing so always. Short names are no longer reliable.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Could you mark an answer or provide one yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a problem connecting to the DNS server.

- try using dig to resolve the host with your internal DNS: `dig @your-internal-dns uksvl-web01-rs`
- check if the DNS-port is open for your virtual host: `telnet your-internal-dns 53`

Comment: `telnet` only tests TCP where DNS uses also UDP. So no need to do this, just use `dig +tcp` to force TCP connection, or `dig +notcp` to force UDP.

Comment: Today I won't recommend telnet anyway. You may want to use netcat (nc) instead, which even supports UDP. @PatrickMevzek is correct: you may just add the `+tcp` or `+notcp` option, but nc may also help.

Answer (score 1):

After configuration netplan (on LXC container) with new DNS servers, and after `netplan apply`, my */etc/systemd/resolved.conf* was without DNS servers, so I added them manually and executed `service systemd-resolved restart`

This is a temporary solution, but I need this only for remove netplan. Maybe this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issue. I disabled dnssec (DNSSEC=no) in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and it helped.

Comment: It's unlikely that DNSSEC is the reason for problems with private zones.

Answer (score -3):

create a host entry in /etc/hosts.
then try

Comment: Doesn't really help me solve the issue, I have a perfectly working DNS server that has 100's of entries, adding them all to hosts is not a practical approach.